# Encoding 20-bit number across bytes in Go

Tags: go, binary

I have the following layout I am trying to achieve in Go.

At the moment I can work out how to encode/set bits 6 & 7 from Byte 0

```
// Element ID flag
bytesToSend[0] |= (1 << 7)

//N/S Flag 
bytesToSend[0] |= (1 << 6)
```

I cannot work out however how to encode the 20-bit "Block Number" in Go.

I do think that to read it I will be doing...

```
block_num_out := ((int(bytesToSend[0]) & 0x0f) << 16) | (int(bytesToSend[1]) << 8) | (int(bytesToSend[2]))
```

My encoding I have tried...

```
block_num_in := 343348
bytesToSend[0] |= block_num_in << 16
```

But this gives an error of...

`invalid operation: bytesToSend[0] |= block_num_in << 16 (mismatched types byte and int)`

I have also tried

```
block_num_in := 343348
bytesToSend[0] |= (byte(block_num_in) << 16) & 0x0f
bytesToSend[1] |= byte(block_num_in) << 8
bytesToSend[2] |= byte(block_num_in)
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

[image: bytes layout]

Comment: If you know how to assemble it from bytes, what causes problem to split it into bytes? It's very similar.

Comment: Thanks @icza.  I have updated the question with what I have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing, you have to use the opposite shifting direction. And since `block_num_in` is of type `int`, you have to convert the result to `byte`:

```
bytesToSend[0] |= byte(block_num_in >> 16 & 0x0f)
bytesToSend[1] = byte(block_num_in >> 8 & 0xff)
bytesToSend[2] = byte(block_num_in)
```

Also if you have to do a lot of bit kung fu involving stepping byte boundaries, consider using [`github.com/icza/bitio`](https://github.com/icza/bitio) (disclosure: I'm the author).

Comment: Amazing thanks.  Am I also right in thinking that the 0xff is actually not needed on the second 2 bytes?

Comment: @LeeArmstrong Yes, you can leave that out, since the `int=>byte` conversion will keep the lowest 8 bits.

Comment: And that is a nice package!